# If there's a hole in Zvezda module, why didn't all the air onboard immediately escape into space?

Tags: iss, pressure, zvezda, leak

The ISS is leaking through a hole in the Zvezda module that still hasn't been found.

However, as with all pressurized chambers, shouldn't all air instantly run out through the hole into the vacuum of space immediately after the hole formed, forcing the astronauts to put on spacesuits?

Or is it rather a valve that's leaking like in case of Soyuz 11 (where however all the air also run out quite quickly, killing the crew)?

Comment: A data point for holes - this 2mm hole https://www.sciencealert.com/russia-knows-what-caused-the-hole-in-the-iss-and-nasa-wants-answers was slow enough they let the crew sleep until morning before starting the search. So this hole is presumably smaller than that one, and a 2mm hole was not considered particularly exciting.

Comment: If you drill a hole in a big plastic bottle using your smallest drill bit it'll take a while for water to leak out of that and air leaking into a vacuum arguably leaks even slower

Comment: Have you ever inflated a balloon, then let it deflate again? Did it a) happen instantly, or b) take some time?

Comment: Analogy: I open the faucet (tap) over my kitchen sink. The entire regional reservoir of two billion gallons immediately dumps into my house. Different viscosity, different fluid, same physical constraints. Matter has inertia, fluids have pressure gradients (not abrupt discontinuities), velocity and acceleration have time dependencies.

Comment: The answers address the main question more than adequately, but something else you might not realize is that the ISS is ALWAYS leaking.  Hatch and mating seals are imperfect!  As long as the leak rate is lower than some limit (which I don't recall), it's not an issue, you just replenish the air like any other consumable supply.

Comment: A better analogy would be to a slow leak in a car tire. Even though the usual pressure difference (2-3 atm) is greater, and the volume much smaller, it can take days or weeks to go flat.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You can't compare a blown-up balloon to a pressurized chamber versus the vacuum of outer space.

Comment: It's this thing called "friction."

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Can you elaborate? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Greenhorn The balloon example absolutely is comparable - big volume, small hole, and the air doesn't escape immediately. In the case of the ISS, it's an even bigger volume and an even smaller hole. What would make you think "all pressurized chambers" would have the contents "instantly run out through the hole" in the first place. Do you think the air teleports out as soon as there's any hole? That's the only way it could happen "instantly". Even when explosives are used, nothing happens *instantly* - just very, very quickly. This leak is just very, very, slow... but persistent.

Comment: @T.J.L. By "instantly" I meant what you call "very, very quickly" and I think you know that. A balloon is inflated versus 1 atm while a spacecraft is inflated towards _no_ exterior pressure in which no human can survive in the clothes they wear within the ISS, the difference between 1 atm and no pressure is infinite (from the exterior point of view) so I would've expected an explosion danger or rapid depressurization or something. (it's actually nanopressure since the ISS is still in the thermosphere)

Comment: @Greenhorn  If  gas molecules didn't exhibit friction both between each other and, more important, with the walls of the opening, then the gas would indeed exit almost immediately.  Take a look at articles on superfluids and "second sound" for analogous behavior.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Now I see.

Comment: @Greenhorn: The "no exterior pressure" is irrelevant.  All that matters is the pressure difference.

Comment: And the flow chokes as long as the outside pressure is less than about half that of the inside pressure. Further reductions in the outside pressure don't change the flowrate. Read the wikipedia article on choked flow.

Comment: @Greenhorn Pressure difference is additive, not multiplicative. The difference isn't "infinite": it's about 1 atm. Vacuum doesn't suck: pressure pushes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It would take around 7 hours to depressurize the ISS through a bullet hole. See http://www.spaceacademy.net.au/flight/emg/spcdp.htm

Smaller holes will take longer. A tiny crack might take days to even cause a noticeable pressure drop. The ISS is not 100% leak-proof, so some small amount of air needs to be added on a regular basis to top it up. Further, the ISS spends roughly half of its time on the day side, and half on night side of the planet. This means it goes from pretty hot to really cold, causing metal to expand and contract. It's possible the small leak only occurs when its hot, or cold, so around half the time.

Answer (score 18):

The pressure difference between the inside and outside of the ISS is one atmosphere. This is the same pressure difference between the bottom of a 10 meter tank of water and the outside at sea level or minimum [legal water pressure in the UK](https://www.watersafe.org.uk/advice/common_plumbing_questions1/pressure/what_is_the_minimum_water_pressure_that_a_water_supplier_must_supply/)

The behavior of air and water in detail is different but a first order approximation of fluid behavior VS hole size will be similar for a space craft leak and leaks in domestic plumbing (noting your actual mains pressure may be two or even three atmospheres) - undesirable over various time scales but not instantaneous even at quite substantial opening sizes (think shower head or open tap).

Comment: Doesn't it matter that there's ultra-vacuum outside, a pressure far beyond the Armstrong limit?

Comment: @Greenhorn pressure difference is the same so the mechanical loads are the same, which is counteintuative but how physics works.  Also means they can test spacecraft (and airliners) just by pumping them up above ambient to the required level to simulate flight. There are a number of things like vapor pressure that DO make a difference with a hard vacuum (and having your sealing grease evaporate can of course cause a leak) but the 'how fast does fluid flow is consistant.

Comment: So basically it's like a spacewalk without a spacesuit, because all the astronauts onboard aren't shut up from the outside.

Comment: @Greenhorn a lot of scientists would *love* for creating "ultra-vacuum" to be as easy as you imply. Lots of science could be done more easily and cheaply. However, the more gas escapes, the less pressure there is to remove the remainder.

Comment: The difference between a pretty poor vacuum (call it 0.01psi) and ultra vacuum (0) is only another 0.01psi ... makes no difference to the rate of atmospheric pressure (14.6psi) air escape.

Answer (score 12):

It is easy to conduct simple home experiments, or even do them as thought experiments to determine the answer to this question.

Think of a child's balloon. Inflate the balloon with air whilst holding the neck of the balloon with your fingers:

[image: Boy inflating a balloon]

Now relax the pressure on the neck of the balloon **very slightly**. You will find that the air leaks  out of the balloon very slowly. It does not all escape instantly. It takes time. This is because the molecules of gas (air) cannot all move through the exit at the same time. They have to move towards it before they can exit. A bit like people rushing through an exit:

[image: people trying to leave via the fire exit]

The same is true for a space vehicle. With a small exit the air molecules will take time to pass through the very small hole. If the hole is small enough the lost air can be replaced. However, if the whole is large enough the the air will escape more rapidly:

[image: Dave Bowman blowing the airlock door in 2001]

Comment: But why doesn't the Zvezda module explode when the air tries to escape as rapidly as usual with pressurized chambers? On airliners this is what sometimes happens but I suspect that on the ISS there's construction preventing an explosion, right?

Comment: @Greenhorn Big room, small hole. Very small hole.

Comment: @Greenhorn - may be worth chasing down the early mythbusters episode on airliner decompression to separate movie from reality in decompression effects, took them blowing an entire window out with a shaped charge to get 'explosion' type effects in the cabin and even there the plane was structurally fine other than the missing window. Smaller things like bullet holes just made a lot of noise.

Comment: @GremlinWranger https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloha_Airlines_Flight_243

Comment: @geoffc How small do you think the hole is?

Comment: @Greenhorn was thinking of linking that one, per the investigation section that was internal pressure tearing open a fatigue failure to make a big hole, not a pinhole that magically turned into an aircraft with a sunroof. Aloha airlines would have been fine if the structure around where the hole started had been sound - so yes you are right that if this leak is a weak point being cycled open and propagating down a seam it could fail in a similar very exciting way. If it is in otherwise sound material this is as bad as it will get.

Comment: @GremlinWranger How small do you think the hole is in the first place? I mean, is it of microscopic size (in such case, all is clear) or is it a proper clearly recognizable crack? I suppose it's the latter one, otherwise astronauts couldn't look for it outside, right?

Comment: @Greenhorn - my completely uninformed guess based on them not having found it and having chased pressure leaks in more boring circumstances is that they have a threaded fixture of some sort, possibly on a valve and air is working down the length of the thread and out - so cross sectional area fraction of a mm and a long path - easy enough to find if you can dunk the offending part in water and look for the faint trail of bubbles, not so much here!

Comment: @geoffc damn, you beat me to it.  That in seven words is all the answer that's needed.

Comment: @Greenhorn are you being purposefully obtuse by trying to compare a small hole in a structurally sound airplane (Myth Busters) to a plane (Aloha 243) with metal fatigue?